# How long will it take to add a fulltext index to a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, full-text-indexing

I have a MySQL table with 66 million rows and want to add a full-text index to a varchar(255) column in that table.

Is there a time-to-execute calculator or a formula that I can use to work out how long it will take to create this index?

I know that server specs will impact this so let's say an appropriately sized server for the DB.

EDIT: I do not have access to this database and the only chance I will have to add this index is during a production switch-over so there's no possibility to test this with a subset of rows.

Comment: Fair comment, I've edited it and added the info you are asking about.

Comment: You can always make a fake version of same by creating a database with heaps of similar data, random words from the dictionary or snippets from [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/).

Comment: @Guy While I feel for you, production DB schema changes should *always* be done in an integration environment first (and more testing/dev environments, if possible). You don't really care about the *specific* data (like tadman alludes to), just the *amount* of data.